# Zero size struct

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I noticed that when compiled with GCC 4.6 `sizeof(Foo)` is 0 and `sizeof(Bar)` is 1. For some reason adding an empty array into an empty structure made its size 0. I thought that the sizes of both structures must be the same. What is going on here?

```
struct Foo
{
    char x[];
};

struct Bar {};
```

Comment: That's odd, `sizeof` can never be _0_...

Comment: @K-ballo: For flexible arrays like `char x[]` sizeof is 0.

Comment: @Tudor: Flexible arrays, is that a compiler extension?

Comment: @K-ballo No, it's in the standard since C99. But a struct that has a flexible array member must have more than one named member.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I guess this is one of those things in which _C_ and _C++_ differ...

Comment: @K-ballo From [gcc extension docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html): _Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied. As a quirk of the original implementation of zero-length arrays, sizeof evaluates to zero._

Comment: gcc 4.2 here reports a compiler error: _error: flexible array member in otherwise empty struct_, which agrees with the blurb from the extension docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can this structure have sizeof == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352663/how-can-this-structure-have-sizeof-0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither `struct` declaration is allowed by the C standard. 6.7.2.1 (8) in n1570:

> If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any named members, either directly or via an anonymous structure or anonymous union, the behavior is undeﬁned.

And paragraph 18 in the same section:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure **with more than one named member** may have an incomplete array type; this is called a ﬂexible array member. In most situations, the ﬂexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the ﬂexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply.

(emphasis mine)

Flexible array members are not allowed in C++, so the code is not valid C++ either.

As it is not valid code, the values reported by `sizeof` for these are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The sizeof operator never yields 0, even for an empty class.

as you can see [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

furthermore the msdn is stating:

The sizeof operator cannot be used with the following operands:

- Functions. (However, sizeof can be applied to pointers to functions.)
- Bit fields.
- Undefined classes.
- The type void.
- Dynamically allocated arrays.
- External arrays.
- Incomplete types.
- Parenthesized names of incomplete types.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ do not permit zero-sized objects.

gcc does support them *as an extension*.  If you compile with the proper options, such as

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
```

gcc will at least warn you about them; g++ has similar options.