# gcc compiler reporting size of class=zero

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have the small program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class xyz{
   private: int xyz[];  // Why this line is not giving error.
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout<<sizeof(xyz); //Q=Why this code is not giving error.
    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc 4.3. Please tell me why am I wrong?

Comment: That does seem odd - later versions of gcc also seem to give the same result (0), and no warnings when compiled with `g++ -Wall ...`. `clang` gives a warning for the unused private field, but that's all.

Comment: GCC 4.3 is very old, and less C++ standard conforming than newer version. Newer GCC gives also better diagnostics and optimizations. Try updating your GCC to GCC 4.8.1 (or at least 4.7.3) and use `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: @Basile: I've tried gcc 4.8 and it's the same.

Comment: @PaulR I tried with checking "g++ -Wall -o check check.cpp" but didn't get any warnings as such:

Comment: @Santosh: same here (see above comment).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10971651/841108

Comment: So is there no way to get warnings in the compiler i am using?

Comment: @Basile: good catch on that duplicate.

Comment: And who are these downvoting people?

Comment: I've now tried various versions of gcc, clang and Intel's ICC and they all give the same result - no warnings, and sizeof(xyz) = 0.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is a g++ compiler extension. You can trigger the warning

```
ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'xyz'
```

if you compile with the `-Wpedantic` flag, and you can stop it from compiling using the `-pedantic-errors` flag. The reason your output shows `0` is that g++ will translate that into (the also not standard conforming) `int[0]`. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627235/how-do-compilers-treat-variable-length-arrays) for more information.

Comment: It seems to be more widespread than just gcc.

Comment: @PaulR That's true, but this question is gcc specific; "this is a g++ compiler extension" does not say other compilers don't have it as well ;)

Comment: -pedantic extension makes my compiler generate warining for the "ISO C++ forbids zero-size array âaâ".